# how to parse nserror received from stripe

Tags: swift, stripe-payments, nserror

Hello when i enter some incorrect card number i am getting this type error

> Error Domain=com.stripe.lib Code=70 "Your card was declined"
>   UserInfo={com.stripe.lib:ErrorMessageKey=Your card was declined. Your
>   request was in live mode, but used a known test card.,
>   com.stripe.lib:StripeErrorCodeKey=card_declined,
>   com.stripe.lib:StripeErrorTypeKey=card_error,
>   com.stripe.lib:CardErrorCodeKey=com.stripe.lib:CardDeclined,
>   com.stripe.lib:ErrorParameterKey=, NSLocalizedDescription=Your card
>   was declined}

i want to parse this message from the following error

> Your card was declined. Your request was in live mode, but used a
>   known test card.

Comment: but i want this "Your card was declined. Your request was in live mode, but used a known test card."

Comment: see lib:ErrorMessageKey from the above question

Comment: Did you try `error.localizedDescription`?

Comment: yes it was giving only title of the message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the `error` as `NSError` and then you can access the `userInfo` and check all the `keys` in that `dictionary` and extract whatever message-value you want,

```
if let error = error as? NSError {
    print(error.userInfo)
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    // Check the userInfo object and extract the messages as error.userInfo["messageKey"]
}
```